# phpMyAdmin - how to define a FK constraint on a complex key

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I am familiar with foreign keys and referential integrity.  I have a table in which the PK is made up of two fields.  That PK is also part of the primary key in a child table.  When the parent record is deleted, I want the child record deleted as well (cascade delete).  I know how to define a complex fk constraint on the child table using SQL.

How do you define a complex fk key constraint through the phpMyAdmin user interface with the relations view?  There does not appear to be a mechanism for having the constraint based on a two field combination.

I only want the child record deleted if the parent table record is deleted, which means both fields that make up the foreign key are being deleted and not just one.

Thanks in advance for anyone who can tell me how to do this or for letting me know it is not possible.